# Who is the character with Palutena?

Tags: game-identification

While browsing images of Super Smash Brothers 3DS/WiiU, I came across this one:

[image: WiiU Screenshot]

I recognize the character on the right to be Palutena.  Who is the character on the left?

Comment: While the game is currently "unreleased content", all characters are from other series, so the character should be from a currently available game.  I also realize this is more character-identification than game-identification, but I'm unsure we want to make that tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is [Phosphora （エレカ Ereka)](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Lightning_Flash_Phosphora) from Kid Icarus: Uprising. And, quoted from that Wiki page:

> Phosphora is confirmed to appear as a trophy in the upcoming Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 3DS/Wii U.

[image: Trophy from SSB WiiU]